# Submit without validation

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have problem to make simple online form

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" required>
<input type="text" name="job" required>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save My Data">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Form">
</form>
```

This form have multiple button submit with multiple condition. As default (click next form button), you cannot submit if you have not answered all required fields, but if you answered name and click save my data button you allowed to submit even job is leave blank

Is possible to make it ? Please give me example so that the required field can be skipped

Comment: yup..checkout `ajax`

Answer (score 2):

Add these scripts inside your html head tag. It will work

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('input[name="job"]').attr('required');
         $('input[name="save"]').click(function(){
                   $('input[name="job"]').removeAttr('required');
         });
         $('input[name="next"]').click(function(){
                  $('input[name="job"]').attr('required','required');
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this try to give id to your input fields and then access them from javascript i.e.

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" required id="name">
<input type="text" name="job" required id="job">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save My Data" id="savebtn">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Form" id="nextbtn">
</form>
```

Now in script:

```
$("#savebtn").click(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#name").length>0 || $("#job").lenght>0){
        $(this).submit();
    }
}

$("#nextbtn").click(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#name").length>0 && $("#job").lenght>0){
        $(this).submit();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.